# Replacing an instance of Base with an instance of Derived in a std::vector cell

Tags: c++, vector, replace, derived-class, base-class

Suppose I have a base class `Base` and a derived class `Derived` as well as a `std::vector<Base> vec(k)` that is being initialised with `k` `Base` instances.

How would I go about replacing instances of `Base` with instances of `Derived` while iterating over the vector?

If the classes were not hierarchically structured like ints I could just do this:

```
for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end();)
{
    if (j == 3)
    {
        *i = 9;
    }
    else
    {
        ++i;
     }
}
```

But with derived and base classes this does not work, as this shows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<ostream>

class Base
{

public:

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, Base& e)
    {
        return o << e.get_repr();
    }

private:

    virtual std::string get_repr()
    {
        return repr;
    }

private:

    std::string repr = "B";
};

class Derived: public Base
{

private:

    std::string get_repr()
    {
        return repr;
    }

private:

    std::string repr = "D";
};






int main()
{

    std::vector<Base> vec(5);

    int j = 0;
    for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++j)
    {
        if (j == 3)
    {
        *i = Derived();
    }
    else
    {
        ++i;
    }
    }

    for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

the output being:

`B B B B B`

So how can I replace the `Base`-instance with a `Derived`-instance?

## Edit

I changed the cell contents to pointers, as suggested in the comments. I did it like this:

```
int main()
{

    std::vector<Base*> vec(5);

    int j = 0;
    for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++j)
    {
        if (j == 3)
        {
            *i = new Derived();
        }
        else
        {
            *i = new Base();
            ++i;
        }
    }

    for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << **i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

but I am still getting `B B B B B`... why?

Comment: You can't since you have concrete `Base` objects in your vector, any attempt would result to object slicing.

Comment: Change the vector to `std::vector<Base*>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` and then use `static_cast<Derived*>` (in the former case) to cast to derived class

Comment: I thought vector stored only pointers in its cells anyway, placing the objects in the ram...?

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury I also tried implementing your solution, but I am still getting the same result. I edited the question.

Comment: @lotolmencre `get_repr()` has `private` access in your class `Base` meaning it can't be overridden in `Derived`. Change this access to `protected`.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury Oh, I see, yes. But  actually  I can do `Base* b = new Base();
    b = new Derived();
    std::cout << *b << std::endl;` giving me `D`, without changing `get_repr()` to `protected`. But when doing the same thing in the loop (with changing `get_repr()` to `protected`) the result is still `B B B B B`... Which I find kinda puzzling.